First paper submission reproducibility AAAi25
I'm preparing my submission for AAAI25, and I came across the requirement for a reproducibility checklist. I am a bit confused about how this checklist should be submitted. Should it be included as an appendix in the main paper, or is it something that needs to be uploaded as a separate document? Also, if it is included in the paper, does it count for the page limit?
Any insights from those who have submitted to AAAI before or have experience with this process would be really appreciated! This is my first submission, so I am afraid to mess it up.

Can anybody help me with that?

In the first appearance of 'AAAI25' you should give the full name (e.g. something like "AAAI25 (xxx)", where 'xxx' is the full name). Then reproduce the checklist here or provide a link. Also, since AAAI25 and AAAI are (presumably) different acronyms, you should say what the latter is, unless it's clear from knowing the former acronym. I googled "AAAI25", so I think I know what it is, but since what I found is so recent (last 2 to 3 years), I could be wrong, and anyway anything that recent might not be all that standard yet in whatever field you're in, which incidentally you did not tell us.

@DaveLRenfro: Thanks for the answer, but I do not get where to include the checklist. Are we referring to the same thing. https://aaai.org/conference/aaai/aaai-25/submission-instructions/ .Maybe  you can have a look at this. Sorry for that but I cannot ask anybody else. Can I provide an extra document where I can add this list or do I have to include it in the main paper?

Thanks for the answer -- I wasn't giving an answer. I was mentioning some ways that you can revise your question to make it more understandable for others here, "ways" that are very quick and easy to implement (probably only a handful of words added in a couple of places) but which would greatly increase it's intelligibility.

These answers are all wrong.
In OpenReview, when you edit your submission, under "Reproducability Checklist", there is a small text that states "Authors are required to complete a Reproducibility Checklist (https://aaai.org/conference/aaai/aaai-25/aaai-25-reproducibility-checklist/). Please include your answers in your PDF after the references.".
I therefore added the reproducability checklist after my references together with my answers.

Thank you very much. You saved my day.

You are running up against the deadline.
The checklist appears to be supplementary material and you have until August 19 anytime on earth to submit it together with your code.
You should address these questions to the conference, though. I just answer because you seem to have entered panic mode.
Good luck with your submission.
